# Facebook Messenger backup - buggy files, problems with charmap

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, notepad++, emeditor

I made a backup of Facebook Messenger. It's saved as default, as html file. Each file for each person I spoke with. The biggest file I have is over 80MB. When I open It I can see that there are thousands of typos in the code. The code shows Á or Å  instead of A, æ instead of ae and so on, and so on..

In such state I can not open it and read thru any program as it's ending with charmap errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Filip/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    messages = open("message.html","r").read()
  File "C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1917064: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is it problem with my file editor, download problem (it took over 8h to download 5GB - thanks, Facebook) or simply such big text files saved in single line has no chance to work correctly?

I was trying to open file in:

-Notepad

-EmEditor - ironically, it had even worse time working with file than Notepad

EDIT 1:

Ok, I managed to split the whole htlm code to simply pure txt like:

```
=A=
jakiefry
15November201511:34
=F=
mediumfry
15November201511:34
=A=
xD
15November201511:34
=A=
mozemediumjestemjakies
15November201511:34
=F=
xDD
15November201511:34
=A=
iostatniotyledejavumam
15November201511:34
...(900 000 lines more)
```

And read it line by line, until it find the problematic line. I used this code:

```
f = open('messege.txt')
try:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        print(line)
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
except Exception:
    stop = input("stop before it crash")
    print("and when I press enter it crash")
```

Now I'm looking for the way to delete problematic line, or simply skip it. Maybe while reading should I be creating the new file, where all good lines will be saved only? But still, how to skip line that makes error so it's happy to continue. Stay tuned folks, new updates coming ;)

Comment: Perhaps you are trying ro read an unicode file as an ANSI one? What's the encoding of the file? Also, why you consider `æ` a typo?

Comment: @Julio, I found the problem source. As it's conscript from the chat, it consists a lot of non-standard characters. Hearths and emoticons,different foreign language characters and other random characters.

Comment: will opening the file as utf8 work for you? `import io` `with io.open('messege.txt','r',encoding='utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was:

1. Divide code in lines.

To avoid working with HTML code, I opened it in browser and copy/paste chat history to notepad++. Then saved as txt file.

2. Clean code line by line.

To to do I wrote a script that read code line by line and in case of error, simply and skip it. Each line that gives no error is saved in new file.

```
file_old = open('fobarfoo.txt')
file_new = open('foobarfoo_new.txt', 'w+')
error_counter = 0 

line = file_old.readline()
while line:
    try:
        while line:
            file_new.write(line)
            line = file_old.readline()
        file_old.close()
    except Exception:
        error_counter += 1
        #stop = input("stop before it crash")
print(error_counter)
```

So the output is new file only with characters or lines of the code, that generate no charmap errors.